# How to select int that are not in some other list ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some List that contain int value between 0 to 10 
for example the list contain the values    3, 8 ,9, 10

Now, i want to use linq to create new list that will contain all the values that are not in the first list ... that mean that the new list will contain the values 0,1,2,4,5,6,7

How to do it with linq ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myNums = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Except(yourList);
```

It's `11` instead of `10` because that's the count of numbers you wish to generate, and there are 11 numbers in 0-10 inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

**if** the new list has to be limited again by `0-10`, you can do

```
var myList =  new List<int>{3, 8 ,9, 10};
var resultList = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Except(myList );
```

Comment: your `.Range()` 2nd parameter should be `11`, because that is the count of items to output. The range 0 to 10 actually has 11 numbers. In other words, `.Range(0,1)` would just output the set `{ 0 }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] seq1={3,5,8},seq2={5,7,8};
seq2.Except(seq1);//7
```